# How to check JSessionID is valid in server end

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have 2 systems(A&B) which I would like to implement SSO(single sign on) between them. I would like A system to be the on-line check manage system, B system will send the JSESSIONID to A, to check whether this sessionid is valid in A's session pool. How to implement this interface in A system?

In A system, I used request.getSession() to get the right session, which not have the JSESSIONID parameter.

WEBSERVER : using TOMCAT.

Comment: Tomcat already has SSO. You don't have to implement it yourself. See the Tomcat documentation.

Answer (score 2):

EJP has actually answered your question. You will definitely want to look into [Single Sign On](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html#Single_Sign_On) from tomcat documentation. In tomcat `server.xml` uncomment the `valve` with classname `org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn`. If you found it is difficult to implement into your existing systems A and system B, you should get this [book](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html), as it has explanation on how to configure sso in tomcat. Check out the [link](http://oreilly.com/java/archive/tomcat-tips.html) on page two.

Comment: Noting however that the book and link are 9 years old, where the Tomcat documentation is up to date, and IMHO says exactly the same thing free.

Comment: Yea, it's pretty old I know, there is second version of it. My point is that, rather than no book to read, it will be give steep difficulty for starter. Sometime, when we are learning, a little minor error actually drive us to find the solution and that actually turn on the brain to think. Just my two cents.

Comment: Agreed, but (a) the product's own documentation is the primary reference, not a 3rd party book, and (b) in point of fact the link you provided just appears to more or less reiterate the Tomcat documentation. There is no improvement in ease of reading.